# C++ - Creating a Copy function without = assignment for a Dynamic String Array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, compiler-errors, c++14

Trying to write a copy function for a dynamically allocated array.

In my header file I have:

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>


using std::string;
using std::unique_ptr;
using std::make_unique;

class StringSet{
public:
    //create an empty set
    StringSet() = default;
    StringSet(int capacity);

    //copy a set
    StringSet(const StringSet&);

    StringSet& operator[](const int);

    //Insert a string to the set
    bool insert(string);

    //Remove a string from the set
    bool remove(string);

    //Test whether a string is in the set
    int find(string) const;

    //Get the size of the set
    int size() const;

    //get string at position i
    string get(int i) const;

    //Return the set union of the set and another StringSet
    StringSet setunion(const StringSet&) const;

    //Return the intersection of the set and another StringSet
    StringSet intersection(const StringSet&) const;

    //Return the set diffference of the set and another StringSet
    StringSet difference(const StringSet&) const;

    //prevent default copy assignment
    StringSet& operator=(const StringSet&) = delete;

    int NOT_FOUND = -1;
    static constexpr int def_capacity {4};

private:
    int arrSize {def_capacity};
    int currentSize {0};
    unique_ptr<string[]> arr {make_unique<string[]>(def_capacity)};

};
```

In my implementation file I have:

```
#include "StringSet.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>



StringSet::StringSet(int capacity)
: arrSize{capacity},
    arr{make_unique<string[]>(capacity)}
{
}

StringSet::StringSet(const StringSet& a)
{
    auto a2 = StringSet(currentSize);

    for (auto i=0; i < currentSize ; i++ )
        {
        a2[i] = a[i];
        }
}
```

Compiler error:

```
error: constructors may not be cv-qualified
error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'StringSet' and 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}')
error: passing 'const StringSet' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
error: use of deleted function 'StringSet& StringSet::operator=(const StringSet&)'
```

My assignment has overloaded the assignment operator= and thus I'm not able to use that here. Is there another way of implementing a copy function without using the assignment operator - is there anything in std::string that allows us to copy contents easier in this manner?

If there's anything else I need to add here for details please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: shouldn't it be "string& operator[](const int);" instead of "StringSet& operator[](const int);"? Also, you should define a "const string& operator[](const int) const;"

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this code:

```
StringSet::StringSet(const StringSet& a)
{
    auto a2 = StringSet(currentSize);

    for (auto i=0; i < currentSize ; i++ )
    {
        a2[i] = a[i];
    }
}
```

is that, even if it compiled, you're never actually initializing the members of `this`... you're initializing some temporary `a2` that goes out of scope at the end of the constructor. You actually want:

```
StringSet::StringSet(const StringSet& a)
    : StringSet(a.arrSize)
{
    currentSize = a.currentSize;

    for (auto i=0; i < currentSize; i++ )
    {
        arr[i] = a.arr[i];
    }
}
```

---

Also, your `operator[]` returns a `StringSet&` where it should probably return a `std::string&`.

Also, you should avoid bringing names into the global namespace like you're doing. Keep it local. Writing `std::` is not a burden.

Comment: `auto a2 = StringSet(currentSize);` would even be infinite loop.

Comment: Yea I was mistaken about doing the `auto a2 = StringSet(currentSize)` when I actually wanted arrSize. 

I didn't know arr was the way of referring to the local instance of the array initialized in the copy function though. That definitely clears some of the problems up. 
`error: constructors may not be cv-qualified` What does this mean though?

Comment: @TigerCode I'm guessing some constructor you have that you didn't include in your question is cv-qualified. That's not allowed.

Comment: In the header file - for the copy function i forgot to include a place holder for the variable.

Comment: I tried assigning a2 to be the copied a1 array by `auto a2 = StringSet(a1&);` which gave me the errors `error: expected primary-expression before '(' token.` and `error: expected primary-expression before ')' token.` What am i doing incorrectly here?

Comment: @TigerCode Comments aren't for followup questions. I have no idea what `a2` or `a1` are, or why you have that  extra `&`